# Connection Issue with .NET: Exception during Testing compared to SOAP

Tags: .net, https, ssl-certificate, response

I would like to consult an endpoint. When I tested it using SOAP, I received a positive result. However, when I tested it using .NET, I encountered the following exception: "Exception: System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
You will find attached test using soap and test using .Net 5.

Test using Dotnet 5 :  "
static async Task Main()
{

```
        string soapRequest = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:ws=""http://ws.ejb.interfaces70.ftress.aspace.com/"">
           <soapenv:Header/>
           <soapenv:Body>
              <ws:primaryAuthenticateUP>
                 <arg0>
                    <code>bo_WEB</code>
                    <allChannels>false</allChannels>
                 </arg0>
                 <arg1>
                    <auditedParameters/>
                    <authenticateNoSession>false</authenticateNoSession>
                    <authenticationTypeCode>
                       <code>AT_CUSTPIN</code>
                       <allAuthenticationTypes>false</allAuthenticationTypes>
                    </authenticationTypeCode>
                    <password>06146675543436</password>
                    <userCode>
                       <code>732803544276</code>
                    </userCode>
                 </arg1>
                 <arg2>
                    <code>cfd</code>
                 </arg2>
              </ws:primaryAuthenticateUP>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>";

        string logFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logpath"];

        TraceListener fileListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(File.CreateText(logFilePath));
        Trace.Listeners.Add(fileListener);

        string serviceUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"]; // Remplacez par l'URL réelle du service SOAP
        Trace.TraceError($"serviceUrl: {serviceUrl}");

        var currentDirectpry = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
            //SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
            SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls13 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11,
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            ClientCertificates = { new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine
            (currentDirectpry, "Testver\\Testver.cer")) }
        };
        Trace.WriteLine("httpClientHandler :" + httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.ToString());

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "YourSOAPAction"); // Remplacez par l'action SOAP réelle
            // Créer le contenu de la requête
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(soapRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
            try
            {

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(serviceUrl, content);
                // Afficher la réponse
                string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                Trace.TraceError($"responseContent: {responseContent}");

                Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.TraceError($"Exception: {ex}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Erreur lors de l'envoi de la requête : {ex.Message}");

                Exception innerException = ex.InnerException;
                while (innerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Inner Exception: {innerException.Message}");
                    innerException = innerException.InnerException;
                }
            }
        }
        fileListener.Flush();
        fileListener.Close();
    }
```

"

thanks for your help.

I want to get a result returned by .NET similar to what is returned by SOAP

Comment: Looks like an SSL exception. Either there is a TLS version or cipher mismatch, or the server doesn't trust your client certificate. Use a Wireshark trace to see what the Server Hello and Client Hello looks like.